# Is it possible to find out the developer of a facebook app?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible? I mean an app that works inside the facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, every application which is registered in facebook contains a [application page](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=175223792502413#!/apps/application.php?id=175223792502413&v=info). If you click on this page, go to the Info Tab and there you will see the name of the developer.

Answer (score 0):

To get to this page, scroll down while using the app. At the bottom left of the webpage you will see the name of the app. Click it and you will go there. Next, use dooonot's directions.